# Creating an Array to download in a zip

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to write image urls to an array which will write to a zip and force a download

When I write the following array

```
$images= array(
    'http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/de532c02488c11e2b62722000a1fbc10_7.jpg',
    'http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/8b9b59e848fb11e2b39e22000a9d0df1_7.jpg'
);
```

Along with the large script at the bottom of this Question, the zip downloads fine.

But when I use the following

```
foreach ($response['data'] as $data) {
    $images[] = $data['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
}
```

The zip downloads but there's a pop up saying the zip is invalid. The foreach that creates the array only writes in the url.

**Code to Download the zip package**

```
# create new zip opbject
$zip = new ZipArchive();

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    # loop through each file
    foreach($images as $image){
        # download file
        $download_file = file_get_contents($image);
        #add it to the zip
        $zip->addFromString(basename($image),$download_file);   
    }

    # close zip
    $zip->close();

    # send the file to the browser as a download

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=download.zip');
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    readfile($tmp_file);
```

I would be grateful if someone could assist as I'm badly stuck on this

Comment: have you double checked what's the content of `$data['images']['standard_resolution']['url']`

Comment: You have to know that images[0], for example, handles only a string of the url only $response['data'][0]['images']['standard_resolution']['url']

Comment: Could you add the output of `print_r($response['data']);` to show us the current structure of the data-node of response? The code works fine when run locally, I also assume a structure problem with the $response array.

Comment: each $data['images']['standard_resolution']['url'] is equal to a url of an image when I print_r both arrays they output the same

Comment: Open the file in a text editor, and check for any leading or trailing white space that might be injected by switching in and out of PHP tags, echoes in your script, or a BOM marker

Comment: I have print_r both arrays and they both output the exact same

**1st output**
`Array ( [0] => http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/8f80e234491a11e2b23022000a1f9ad5_7.jpg [1] => http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/faec80da491711e2a07e22000a1f9a28_7.jpg )`

**2nd output**
`Array ( [0] => http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/de532c02488c11e2b62722000a1fbc10_7.jpg [1] => http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/8b9b59e848fb11e2b39e22000a9d0df1_7.jpg )`

Comment: I would recommend following Mark Baker's suggesting, save the file and open it up in notepad or whatever you got, make sure you'll see "PK" as the first two characters.

Comment: the first characters are <!DOCTYPE

Comment: @Donald - so you're echoing a ton of HTML markup when you shouldn't be - your output must be __nothing__ beyond the output generated by readfile(), and your headers

Comment: I would recommend checking where you start outputting content and change your script so the unwanted HTML content can be avoided. In case output_buffering is on, try clearing your output buffers using  [ob_clean](http://de2.php.net/ob_clean) and then use readfile() on the zip archive.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not my thing, but I think this:

```
# loop through each file
foreach($images as $key=>$value){
    # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($value);
    #add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString(basename($value),$download_file);   
}
```

Comment: Have tried this but still receive the 'Windows cannot open the folder. The compressed zipped folder is invalid' Error when I open the zip folder

Comment: echo out the value of $value, does this give you what you need in the correct format? this is just to see what we get and if it matches what we need

Comment: if i echo $value inside that foreach then it echos the url and it shows up perfectly. But downloading fails to work.

Comment: This should work perfect, i would have to see your zip Class to help more.